# 'LogManager' is an ambiguous reference between .LogManagers

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, common.logging

I am getting the error message,"Error 19 'LogManager' is an ambiguous reference between 'Common.Logging.LogManager' and 'NLog.LogManager'".

In a C# 2008 application I am trying to add nlog open source logging tool to an application that is already using common.logging that was obtained from the following location: http://netcommon.sourceforge.net.

I have added a reference to the NLog file and I have added the Nlog to the using statement.

The problem is both tools use an object called 'LogManager'.

Thus can you tell me how to solve my problem so I can use both Logmanagers.

The following is my code listed below:
     
    
     
       
      
       
     
     
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

```
   using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using Common.Logging;
     using sample;
     using System.Configuration;
     using System.Xml.Linq;  
     using NLog;

namespace sample
{
  public class Etest
  {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); 
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to make sure the *calls* are well qualified.

```
public class Etest
{
   private static Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); 
   private static ILog log = Common.Logging.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define alias for one of them via `using` directive, or use full names.

But I don't think you need reference to NLog if you are using Common.Logging. Because Common.Logging library introduces a simple abstraction to allow you to select a specific logging implementation at runtime. So, **your code should depend only on Common.Logging library**, not some other logging system like log4net, or NLog:

```
using Common.Logging; // only this library is used
...
ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

And configure Common.Logging to use NLog :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" 
               type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>    
    <section name="nlog" 
             type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" 
              layout="${date:format=HH\:MM\:ss} ${logger} ${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I basically need to use NLog as the configuration manager since I want the level of error messages. Also as part of this process, I will be removing common.logging with the nlog logic. Is there a way to just assign the Nlog to a variable? If so, how would setup setup the assign the value to a variable?

Comment: @user1816979 actually Common.Logging adapter provides same level of messages - 'Trace, Debug, Info, Warning, Error, Fatal`. If you really need to use NLog, then it's not that easy like change `using Common.Logging` to `using NLog`. First - you need to change `ILog` to `Logger`. And you for sure have problems with calls to logger, because API is different - NLog uses `{Level}Exception` methods to write exceptions, Common.Logging uses `{Level}` methods for this. Also Common.Logging uses `FormatMessageCallback` for messages formatting. You will have to change all that stuff.